# pip installation of package works from source, fails from package

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools

Here is my project structure

```
~/Workspace/my-app  master ✗                                                                                                                            ◒
➢  tree -L 2
.
├── build
│   ├── bdist.macosx-10.14-x86_64
│   └── lib
├── dist
│   ├── my-app-0.0.4a0.tar.gz
│   └── my_app-0.0.4a0-py3-none-any.whl
├── gkeconf
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── commands.py
│   └── messages.py
├── main.py
├── my-app
│   ├── __init__.py
├── my_app.egg-info
│   ├── PKG-INFO
│   ├── SOURCES.txt
│   ├── dependency_links.txt
│   ├── entry_points.txt
│   ├── requires.txt
│   └── top_level.txt
├── setup.cfg
└── setup.py
```

And here is my `setup.py`

```
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'my-app=main:cli',
        ],
```

When i perform from the source code dir

```
pip install --editable .
```

running say, `my-app --version` works.

When I build the package via

```
python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
```

and push it to my private repo via

```
python3 -m twine upload --verbose --repository my-private-repo dist/*
```

and then perform

```
pip install my-app
```

(in a new fresh virtualenv)

and try to run it, it fails as follows:

```
➢  my-app --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/pkaramol/Desktop/.myvenv/bin/my-app", line 6, in <module>
    from main import cli
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'
(.myvenv)
```

Why?

**MAJOR_UPDATE**: It seems the `--editable` flag made the difference. Plain `pip install .` yields the same error!

**edit**: `pip install --editable` from other path also works:

Comment: Aren't you missing an `__init__.py` in the root of the package (where the `main.py` is)? Also, can you try the command `pip install --editable .` you posted from another place but the source directory (with the correct path of course, not `.`)?

Comment: I added the `__init__.py` at the root project level without success

Comment: You should not import from main. It is very prone to breaking your program and also makes it sticky if your program has multiple entry-points. If you every wanted to extract some subset of your functionality into a standalone library you have to redefine every orphan reference in your application to make it usable outside of your app.

Comment: @neko I have updated my answer with what happens when I try to install from a different repo

Answer (score 0):

cjange name from `my-app` to `my_app`

Move `main` to `my_app`

change in `setup.py`

```
 entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'my-app=my_app.main:cli',
        ],
```

Your problem is that your `main.py` script is not a part of package. 
 If you install if via method `pip install -e` then pip only create simlink and find the `main.py` file. In normal installation it is not copied.